# If statement based on StartsWith not finding "\\" in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, startswith

I have a string called `fileNameArrayEdited` which contains `"\\windows"`.The below `if` statement is not running.

**Thinking the problem is else where as people have given me code that should work will be back once I found the problem... thanks!**

```
if (fileNameArrayEdited.StartsWith("\\"))
{
    specifiedDirCount = specifiedDirCount + 1;
}

                // Put all file names in root directory into array.
            string[] fileNameArray = Directory.GetFiles(@specifiedDir);
            int specifiedDirCount = specifiedDir.Count();
            string fileNameArrayEdited = specifiedDir.Remove(0, specifiedDirCount);
            Console.WriteLine(specifiedDir.Remove(0, specifiedDirCount));
            if (fileNameArrayEdited.StartsWith(@"\\"))
            {
                specifiedDirCount = specifiedDirCount + 1;
                Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: @user3165670 can you post your string  ?

Comment: And please add a tag indicating what language this is

Comment: Yes, which programming language ?

Comment: The string is user defined and the language is c#, sorry about that.

Comment: Note that `"\\"` checks for a *single* backslash. Use either `"\\\\"` or `@"\\"` for a double one.

Comment: That if statement will look for a single \, as \ us the escape charater, two are required to check for it literally (or precede the string declaration with `@`). However, in this case that check for a single should work fine for strings starting with one or more \ characters, so I can't see how that code currently fails. Your input probably doesn't have any \ characters in it.

Comment: Working on why it may be missing out this section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'@'` at the beginning of your string if you are searching for exactly two slash

```
if (fileNameArrayEdited.StartsWith(@"\\"))
{
  specifiedDirCount = specifiedDirCount + 1;
}
```

They are called verbatim strings and they are ignoring escape characters.For better explanation you can take a look at here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

But I suspect in here your one slash is escape character

```
"\\windows"
```

So you must search for one slash like this:

```
if (fileNameArrayEdited.StartsWith(@"\"))
{
  specifiedDirCount = specifiedDirCount + 1;
}
```

Comment: I suspect you're correct but you may want to give some explanation!

Comment: It looks like it should work for me but I can't get it to trigger the if statement.

Comment: Contrary to my previous comment the thought occurs that StartsWith("\\") represents a single slash... which @"\\Windows" has... and so it should match

Comment: @Kiku-Suma are you sure your string `StartsWith` \\windows or just contains \\windows ?

Comment: @Selman22 as the user inputs \windows into the string I think that may be where the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

When we write

```
    string s1 = "\\" ; 
    // actual value stored in  s1 is "\"
    string s2 = @"\\" ; 
    // actual value stored in  s2 is "\\"
```

The second type of `string`(s) are called "verbatim" strings.

Comment: Correct, but if you look at the code \\ does start with \ and so it should return true regardless!

Comment: @Liath I  suspect you are checking for \\ when you should be checking for \ only